# Arduino and industrial stepper driver

Tags: arduino-mega, stepper

For a project I need to use an industrial stepper driver with an arduino. There it is: http://www.omc-stepperonline.com/bipolar-stepper-motor-driver-max-4a-current-40vdc-input-16-subdivision-st6600-p-246.html

The motor: https://prototypes.haydonkerk.com/ecatalog/hybrid-linear-actuators/en/linear-actuator-57F42-3.25-099#

I'm not familiar with this driver, so can I use it with the Arduino Stepper Library?

I didn't see a lot of tutorial for this driver compared to many other popular driver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely you can. Looking at the picture, this is set up for bipolar and a unipolar motor. There you have to wire according to the wire diagram.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure with the configuration of the function ''Stepper(steps, pin1, pin2, pin3, pin4)''. Which pin goes to Pul, Dir and Ena?

Comment: I have no idea what do you mean by Pul, Dir and Ena

Comment: I have not read deep into it , but It looks like this driver has logic attached to it. IT is really not a good driver to be used with you arduino since  it defeats the purpose to get the experience the programing the logic from the Arduino IDE.  Get a Darlington chip or just create your own with transistors and diodes.